# Accidentally removed dist-packages folder, what to do now?

Tags: linux, python, reinstall

I did something very stupid. I was copying some self written packages to the python dist-packages folder, then decided to remove one of them again by just rewriting the `cp` command to `rm`. Now the dist-packages folder is gone. What do I do now? Can I download the normal contents of this folder from somewhere, or do I need to reinstall python completely. If so - is there something I need to be careful about?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740756/accidentally-removed-dist-packages-folder-what-to-do-now

Answer (score -1):

Just try

```
apt-get --reinstall install python
```

You can reinstall your python installation. Tell us if the packages were recovered once you tried

Comment: No, they were not. The folder is still empty.

Comment: The `dist-packages` folder contains third-party modules, not Python itself, so reinstalling Python does not help resolve this situation.